# viewport meta tag html css laravel blade conditions

Tags: html, css, laravel

Hello to all the community, I have a question: is it possible in blade laravel to apply a condition to the meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=0.4"?

I would like the scale to start from 0.4 for smartphones, for tablets from 0.6, is it possible to do this? if so how? thanks so much to the whole community..

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=0.4">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try using the library https://github.com/serbanghita/Mobile-Detect

```php
class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    public function register(): void
    {
        $this->app->singleton('mobile-detect', function ($app) {
            return new MobileDetect();
        });
    }
}
```

### Blade

````php
@if (app('mobile-detect')->isMobile())
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=0.4">
@elseif (app('mobile-detect')->isTablet())
   // TODO
@endif
```
````

Comment: hi thanks for the quick reply, ok I write the code in the appserviceprovider file in the provider folder, but MobileDetect() is highlighted as an error, do I need to insert some dependency? here
namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;

Comment: tried everything installed and written correctly, but it identifies the tablet as mobile, why???

Comment: it's hard for me to say because I don't know the inputs. You should refer to the documentation of the package, it has many features that will help you find the desired

`https://github.com/serbanghita/Mobile-Detect/blob/4.8.x/src/MobileDetect.php`.